# Very slow stored procedure with cursor

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a simple stored procedure to replace empty strings with null in each column of a given table if the data type is varchar or nvarchar.

The procedure works fine for the most part but when it's run over a large table (15 columns with 10,000,000 rows) it can take hours.

I have tested running the updates that would run in the procedure individually and they all take less than a minute on the large tables. This has me thinking there must be something wrong with the procedure. I am new to sql server, is there something wrong here?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_CLEAN_BAD_DATA]

(
      @table_name nvarchar(100)
)

AS
      SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

      DECLARE @column nvarchar(100);

      DECLARE columns CURSOR
      FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
             WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name
             and data_type IN ('VARCHAR', 'NVARCHAR');

      OPEN columns;

      FETCH NEXT FROM columns into @column;

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

             BEGIN                 

                    declare @bad_data_count int = 0,
                    @select_sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT @bad_data_count = COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[' + @table_name + '] WHERE dbo.trim([' + @column + ']) = '''';';                   

                    BEGIN

                          EXEC sp_executesql @select_sql, N'@bad_data_count int OUTPUT', @bad_data_count OUTPUT;

                          if @bad_data_count != 0

                                 BEGIN

                                       DECLARE @update_sql nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE [dbo].[' + @table_name + '] set [' + @column + '] = null WHERE dbo.trim([' + @column + ']) = '''';'
                                       print @update_sql
                                       EXEC sp_executesql @update_sql;

                                 END

                    END

                    FETCH NEXT FROM columns into @column;

             END

      CLOSE columns; DEALLOCATE columns;

END
```

Comment: Not using a `CURSOR` would be a start.

Comment: Using a set-based approach would be the next.

Comment: In fact, what you may want to do is page the rows, not the columns, or possibly both. Updating lots of rows. Do you have any indexes on the table(s) to help the RDBMS find the rows with have a value of `''` too?

Comment: You want to count all the rows in every table, one time for each string column, that have "bad" data in them? That is a scan for every combination. One table with three such columns = three scans of that table. The fact that you're using a cursor to accomplish this is not the part that's making this slow.

Comment: I'm not an expert on SQL injection vulnerability -- but I *think* this is vulnerable.

Comment: It *is* vulnerable, but only if the OP were to have a *really* silly column name, @avery_larry . But then, if someone knows it is, and has the power to add a column with the value `]; DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;--` then they likely already have the power to do whatever they want. Of course, that doesn't mean that should't be making it injection proof.